# What is the best way to use React with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, pug

I am just starting out with React, NodeJS, and Express. Every React tutorial has placed the React code within script tags in an HTML document.

Now I would like to use Express for routing, but Express uses Jade templates in the views by default. I have no idea how to use React within Express, and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for through google searches.

Comment: You do not need to use Jade with express at all.  Just have your express routes send the html files instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's a ReactJS view engine for Express, check it out:

https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views